# Calculating longest Palindrome substring in the String

Tags: java, string, algorithm, complexity-theory

I have the following code for calculating the longest palindrome sub string in the string. The online judge accepts O(n^2) solution but i don't know why  it is not accepting my solution although it seems that my algorithm is O(n^2) in complexity.`

```
class Ideone {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Ideone ob = new Ideone();
        String s = "sds";
        System.out.println(ob.longestPalindrome(s));

    }

    public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
        int maxlength = 1;

        String ps = s.charAt(0) + "";

        if (s.length() == 1)
            return s;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
            int j = (s.substring(i + 1)).indexOf(s.charAt(i)) + i + 1;
            while (j < s.length() && j > i) {
                if (j - i + 1 > maxlength && check(s.substring(i, j + 1))) {

                    maxlength = j - i + 1;
                    ps = s.substring(i, j + 1);

                }
                if ((s.substring(j + 1)).indexOf(s.charAt(i)) < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                j = (s.substring(j + 1)).indexOf(s.charAt(i)) + j + 1;

            }
        }


        return ps;
    }

    public boolean check(String s) {
        int l = s.length();
        if (l == 1)
            return false;
        int t = l / 2;
        String s1, s2;
        if (l % 2 == 0) {
            s1 = s.substring(0, t);
            s2 = s.substring(t);

        } else {
            s1 = s.substring(0, t);
            s2 = s.substring(t + 1);

        }

        s2 = (new StringBuffer(s2)).reverse().toString();

        if (s1.compareTo(s2) == 0)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have your checkt if your code is 0(n²)? create a table and plot a graph of the run times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first glimpse two loops and a method check() which needs O(n) to reverse the String might lead to O(n³).

Be aware that methods like:

- String.indexOf(..)
- String.substring(..)
- String.compareTo(..)
- StringBuffer.reverse(..)
- String.toString()

Need to iterate through the data and therefore need about **O(n)** and not constant time.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This worked for me.Now I am able to figure out why my algorithm was not being accepted .

Comment: reverse() is not the function of String but of StringBuffer..and i want to clarify if substring also takes linear time?Because i think it is a constant time function?correct me if i am wrong..thnx in advance

Comment: @Rishabh Nigam: depending on the implementation of substring it is at least linear in the size of the substring because this data is copied to create new Instance. My answer wasn't about giving a complete list of expensive methods but about the remark that every called methods has to be taken in account to calculate the comlexity.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it will take more than O(n2). Below is program code with dynamic programming .. not java but will be useful as algorithm
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-palindromic-substring-set-2/